# Capistrano Rails deployment with Nginx and Passenger: database credentials being ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, passenger, capistrano3

I'm trying to deploy my first Rails 4 app on an EC2 instance with Capistrano 3. I've followed several tutorials on how to setup the web server with Nginx and Passenger on Ubuntu. I also have a RDS instance for the database with MySQL. But when I try to run `cap deploy` it gives me an error at the `assets:precompile` phase:

```
INFO [d5d05621] Running ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile as deploy@[EC2 PUBLIC IP]
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@[EC2 PUBLIC IP]: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'[EC2 PRIVATE IP]' (using password: NO)
```

From what I understand, it's trying to connect to the database on localhost with the credentials from the development environment.

Here is what my `database.yml` file looks like:

```
development:
    adapter: mysql2
    encoding: utf8
    pool: 5
    socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
    username: root
    password:
    database: Store_development

production:
    adapter: mysql2
    encoding: utf8
    database: Store_production
    username: <%= ENV['STORE_DATABASE_USERNAME'] %>
    password: <%= ENV['STORE_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
    host: [RDS INSTANCE ENDPOINT]
    port: 3306
    pool: 5
    timeout: 5000
```

I looked all over to search for all the places where I could specify the environment, and I ended up having something like this. In my `deploy/production.rb` I have:

```
set :stage, :production
set :rails_env, :production
```

I also have this in the `http` section of `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` on my server:

```
passenger_app_env production;
```

And this in the virtual host configuration in `/etc/nginx/sites-available`

```
passenger_enabled on;
rails_env production;
```

And finally I have this in the `.bashrc` of the deploy user:

```
export RAILS_ENV=production
```

Am I missing something to make the deploy work for the production environment and connect to the RDS instance with the credentials from the `database.yml` file? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the STORE_DATABASE_USERNAME and STORE_DATABASE_PASSWORD environment variables are set on the server and visible to your Rails app. When you SSH into the EC2 instance and run the following do you get the expected values?

```
echo $STORE_DATABASE_USERNAME
echo $STORE_DATABASE_PASSWORD
```

If not, add exports for these to the `.bashrc` of the deploy user:

```
export STORE_DATABASE_USERNAME=< your username >
export STORE_DATABASE_PASSWORD=< your password >
```

Comment: Yes, doing `echo $STORE_DATABASE_USERNAME` prints the expected value, same thing for the password. I've added the exports in the `.bashrc` and also set them in the virtual host config with `passenger_env_var STORE_DATABASE_USERNAME [password];` but the error still comes up.

Comment: Is your database.yml checked into the repo or do you have a shared copy on the server that gets symlinked into the current directory during deploy? It almost sounds like the file is not symlinked or the shared copy is not setup correctly.

Comment: At the beginning I was using the symlink option, I created the `database.yml` file manually in the `shared/config` directory. But after I also tried without the symlink option and it was the same. The `database.yml` is checked into my git repo.